# How do you prevent broadcast storms due to this malicious act?

Tags: networking

A malicious user puts a cross-over cable connecting two ports on the wall to each other, causing the traffic to loop straight back to the switch and the network came down.

Any ideas on what to do about this?  I'm not sure what to think about the entire situation.

edit:  I should note spanning tree was enabled but I don't know what BPDU guard is now that I'm Google Researching.

Comment: Sometimes a non-technical solution is best.  We have the same scenario, and simply using patch cables of the correct length (i.e. too short to reach another jack) ended the problem.

Comment: Don't allow user's near your networking cables.

Comment: I'm pretty sure STP should have stopped that. Are you sure you had it enabled on both ports in question? Maybe ask your vendor why their STP implementation is so broken?